# CKFinder Standalone Error: Folder not found. Please refresh and try again

Tags: php, ckfinder

I have configured my CKFinder standalone but I keep getting

> Folder not found. Please refresh and try again.

What could I have done wrong?
I ensured my `CheckAuthentication()` works fine. My `$baseUrl` is also intact and I tested on my browser to ensure the created folders are accessible. My File Permissions are set to `0755 for folders` and `0777 for filess`

I need a helping hand to figure out what could be wrong.

Comment: Try setting manually `$baseDir` to a proper server side path to your "userfiles" folder. See http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/Configuration/Quick_Start#.24baseDir

Comment: @WiktorWalc It's not complaining about the `$baseDir` since I allowed it to  use `$baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);` I am able to see the folders in the directory but it pops the error when I try accessing them

Comment: One the left side of CKFinder there is the folders pane, which is rendered even if your setup is incorrect or if file system permissions do not allow CKFinder to actually access configured location. The top level folders you see are the names of "resource types" configured in `config.php`. Setting `$baseDir` manually is required if you set $baseUrl to an URL that starts with `http://`. Also setting `$baseDir` manually may help in rare cases when CKFinder is not able to resolve paths for some reason. When you set `$baseDir` to the correct path, make sure that web server has write access there.

Comment: @WiktorWalc I have implemented what you suggested. I called `$baseDir = '/home/login/public_html/ckfinder/files/';` as this yet no way. BaseUrl is in this format `$baseUrl = 'http://example.com/ckfinder/files/';` What more can I do to remedy this situation?

Comment: Create a php file with the following content and run it in your browser: 
`<?php file_put_contents('/home/login/public_html/ckfinder/files/foo.txt', 'test');` Is foo.txt created? If not then permissions to `/home/login/public_html/ckfinder/files/` are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for you lead @WiktorWalc. It created `foo.txt` successfully and the word "test" was written inside of it.

Comment: If CKFinder still does not work, please get in touch with us http://cksource.com/contact and send a link to this topic in a message, we'll debug this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance here @WiktorWalc. I am doing as you recommend at once.

Comment: @WiktorWalc One question here please. If I used my `.htaccess` file to rewrite my URLs and remove the `.php` extensions on my files, will it have any effect on CKFinder?

Comment: It should not if done right. Remember that if you connect CKFinder with CKEditor then e.g. `filebrowserUploadUrl` must point to the correct PHP file. If you change the name of `connector.php`, make sure that `filebrowserUploadUrl` is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @WiktorWalc I'd like you to take a look at this. `# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo/ 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L] 

# add a trailing slash 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R,L] 

# To internally forward /dir/foo/ to /dir/foo.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]
` I found out that commenting `RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L] ` CKFinder works fine. Why is it so please?

Comment: @WiktorWalc Any solutions yet please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of research and reworks, I understood that with the way **CKFinder** requests for files, doing a **rewrite** will halt it's operation in some ways like I experienced which they after all my emails could not say or resolve.

To this end, if you did a rewrite and and ran into issues like

> Folder not found. Please refresh and try again.

best bet is to simply turn off your rewrite rule in the CKFinder's folder

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

That simply solved my problem.

Comment: Can you please share me in which file you changed this??

Comment: @MohammedIqbalKhan I don't know if this will conform to the latest version but you can still try it out. All I did was to create a .htaccess file and add the code above in the root folder of your CKFinder. It will turn off rewrite rule and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your response,I found my solution.Thank you very much for your time...

Comment: @OmniPotens I have created `.htaccess` and also did `RewriteEngine Off` on root folder of `CKFinder`, but not working for me. I am using CKFinder3. If you have any other solution please share. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**CKEditor Image Upload issue:**

**Issue1:** When click on the Browse Server Button, it shows the alert as "Folder not found. Please refresh and try again."

**Issue2:** In the Upload tab, After choose the image file then click Send it to the server button, it shows the alert as "It was not possible to complete the request due to file system permission restrictions."

**Solution1:** 
Open filemanager.config.php:

change this below line

```
$_SESSION['ckeditor']['UserFilesAbsolutePath'] = $_SESSION['ckeditor'][$_GET['id']]['UserFilesAbsolutePath'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['ckeditor']['UserFilesAbsolutePath'] = '/var/www/html/domain/sites/subdomain/files/';
```

**Solution2:**
Open ckediotr.lib.inc:

change this below line

```
$_SESSION['ckeditor'][$profile_name]['UserFilesAbsolutePath'] = strtr($profile->settings['UserFilesAbsolutePath'], array("%f" => variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files'), "%u" => $user->uid, "%b" => base_path(), "%d" => ckeditor_get_document_root_full_path(), "%n" => $user->name));
```

to

```
    $_SESSION['ckeditor'][$profile_name]['UserFilesAbsolutePath'] = strtr($profile->settings['UserFilesAbsolutePath'],
 array("%f" => variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files'), "%u" => $user->uid, "%b" =>**'/domainname/'**, "%d" => ckeditor_get_document_root_full_path(), "%n" => $user->name));
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I changed into the `ckfinder/config.php` file `$baseDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/web/app/webroot/files/ckFinderFiles/';` variable & that did the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can edit config.php of ckfinder

```
// Development
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Edit into

```
// Development
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

To know where the error is.
This is my configuration section you can refer to.
The server I use is Linux Ubuntu.

```
$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => '/files/',
//  'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);
```

Please chmod ckfinder folder to 777
It looks like the file directory is not created, so create the files folder and chmod 777 for it.
My was active.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the solution by setting permission in Ubuntu as follows:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

And the config of `ckfinder/config.php` as follows:

```
$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => 'http://localhost/dmc-burn/upload/ckfinder/userfiles/',
//  'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url - ckfinder/config.php
in this config.php file go to this

$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => 'https://example.com/ckfinder/userfiles/',// here write full path of your site address to folder ckfinder. that its "its work form me."
//  'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);
```